# How to protect server tunneling request in Docker?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

**Problem statement:** 

On the standalone On-Prem server, using nvidia docker. Whenever users create a new environment - they can potentially open up any port for all traffic from outside world(by passing our client firewall) if they don't specify local host variables.

So, how to protect such server tunneling request & instead make it open just for localhost? Any thoughts / ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You can't give untrusted users the direct ability to run `docker` commands.  For instance, anyone who can run a Docker command can run

```
docker run --rm -v /:/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow
```

and then run an offline password cracker to get your host's root password.  Being able to bypass the firewall is probably the least of your concerns.